# Less of a + noun

Tags: meaning

I would like to understand the meaning of the expression: **less of a** + *noun*.

Here a some example sentences: 
 1. Getting there is **less of a** *problem* if you have a car.
 2. It is **less of a** *problem* than I'd expected.

What's the meaning of that expression?
How can I say/express the same without using **less of a** ?

Comment: ***Less of***: to a smaller extent or degree:
*we see less of John these days - 
less of a success than I'd hoped* https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/less-of

Comment: What is it you don't understand about it?

Comment: if I rewrite those sentences as follows, do they mean the same?
1. _Getting there is **NOT REALLY** a problem if you have a car_.
2. _It is **NOT REALLY** a problem than I'd expected_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I say/express the same without using **less of a**?

In your specific sentences, you are talking about ***less of a*** *problem*.

A single-word replacement for *less of a problem* is **easier**:

> Getting there is **easier** if you have a car.
>   It is **easier** than I'd expected.

---

But note that there can be a slight difference in meaning that could make any replacement of *problem* inappropriate.

Some people could consider not having a car to be an *actual* problem. Others could simply be using the word *problem* in the sentence as an indication of degree of effort.

If all you're trying to express is that having a car requires less effort than not having a car, then there is no reason to keep *problem* in the sentence. (And the single-word replacement of *easier* is fine.)

But if you want to maintain the fact that getting there is a problem *regardless* of how you do it (getting to the moon will always present a problem, whether you have a car or not), then removing the word *problem* may not be what you want.

If you keep *problem*, but are still comparing lesser problems with greater problems, then either *less of a problem* or *lesser problem* (if the sentence is additionally reworded) would remain appropriate.

---

On the other hand, if you really want to express that not having a car results in a problem in a way that having a car does not, then it's no longer a matter of *degree* but of the simple assignment of a category. In that case, you could say:

> Getting there is **not** a problem if you have a car.

---

If you are following *less of a* with something other than *problem*, there would likely be different variations. But the use of *less of a* in general is used to compare the degree of one thing with another thing: *X is less of a burden than Y*; *X is less of a celebration than Y.*